# facebook fbml app - Sorry, a temporary error has occurred. Please try again

Tags: facebook, fbml

I have a custom facebook fbml page.  And I have the comments setup by

```
<fb:comments xid="115222541865087"  candelete="true" ></fb:comments>
```

Is gives me an error at every reload...  Sorry, a temporary error has occurred. Please try again.

How do I fix this>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IT appears that this is due to an internal Facebook error.  IT simply went away after a week or so.